# How can I install a python module that doesn't have it's own recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I need to install a python module called flask-socketio in a linux image I am creating using yocto.  However, there is no recipe for this module.

Is there some easy process for taking a python module which can be installed using setuptools, and creating a recipe out of it?

Comment: You should take a look over another (already included in openembedded) python-module recipe, they're usually straightforward to port. If you have any concrete question, do no hesitate to ask.

Comment: https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/master/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python3-flask-socketio_3.3.2.bb
As mentioned, it's already available in master. If you need in specific stable release branch, either you can cherry-pick/copy should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: recipe already exists in mainstream `meta-python` [here](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/master/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python3-flask-socketio_3.3.2.bb) as mentioned by @Parthiban**

Something like this should do it:

**python3-flask-socketio_3.3.2.bb**

```
require python-flask-socketio.inc

inherit setuptools3
```

**python-flask-socketio.inc**

```
DESCRIPTION = "Socket.IO integration for Flask applications"
SECTION = "devel/python"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://PKG-INFO;beginline=8;endline=8;md5=8227180126797a0148f94f483f3e1489"
PYPI_PACKAGE = "Flask-SocketIO"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "298965a43f6534e8a5b24d1ba1fc4186"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "8d8f9f104db5ddff1b06ba322d8e158881d590144199c993fe26cf53218c7edd"

inherit pypi
```

note I didn't test it.

Comment: Thanks!  I will look in to this today.  Do you know if this handles the package prerequisites?  I know flask-socketio needs a socketio package, and then that socketio package needs a bunch of other packages.

Or is this equivalent to just doing a (pip install flask-socketio), where all the prereqs are handled?

Comment: Also, would you mind explaining how you found those hashes for the package?

Comment: By using `inherit pypi`, it will handle everything as `pip install`, but sometimes, its better to create dependency recipes and add `DEPENDS/RDEPENDS` in it, see [this](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/master/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python-pygpgme_0.3.bb). For hash, I downloaded [archive](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/92/eab7ecc11ee151ed2fa0be5aa8bad1b73531e1ae08c366a4df3eebe7f87a/Flask-SocketIO-3.3.2.tar.gz) and executed `md5sum` & `sha256sum`.

Comment: I'd like to point that if you miss the hashes your build will notice it and will stop with an ERROR message (warning you about the missing hashes). You can find the right hashes inside that ERROR message, already calculated by Yocto. If this even happens to you, you only need to copy&paste them in your recipe.

Comment: @danlor that's indeed how I do it most of the time

Comment: So I tried this and it...almost worked.  At least one of the prereq packages was installed (python-six), but the socketio preqreq was not, and the flask-socketio package wasn't.  I can try and set up recipes for other prereq packages as well.  Also, I'm using python2.  The only thing I changed in this recipe was to use switch from "inherit setuptools3" to "inherit setuptools".  Anything else you can think of that I might need to get it working for python 2.7?